# How to find the perimeter of alphabets in javascript on canvas?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, fonts, html5-canvas

I would like to find the perimeter/length of the alphabet written in the canvas. like in below image we can find length of **red line**  and add it.

[image: Sample Image]

Is there any way using javascript.

The thing is, Font type and font size can change as per selection.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It has to be accurate upto 1 mm as I have used sign board to quote a price based on material required.

Comment: The algorithm you're asking about isn't actually related to fonts in the slightest: what you want to do reduce filled shape to their "skeleton" line representation. The shapes just happen to be produced using a font, but the source is entirely irrelevant for this question. As a general graphics question: you can iteratively strip away the "outer layer of pixels", and don't remove any pixel that leaves its neighbours unconnected.

Comment: That said, what you want to actually_do_ has nothing to do with finding that skeleton representation at all: the perimeter of a shape is the total length of its outline path, which for fonts doesn't need to be reconstructed: fonts are already vector graphics. So, load the font in something like OpenType.js, ask it to generate the paths for the text you're looking at, and then just tally the lengths of those paths.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify whether you want perimeter (risk length of the line separating black from white) as your title suggests, or total length of the red skeleton line as your question currently asks, or total area of the black shapes as the application of estimating material would suggest to me. Having this consistent will make the question more useful in the long run.